# Get the filename of running jarfile

Tags: java, jar

Is there any way to know the filename of the running jar that is cross-platform?

I can get the path, I can get the name of all the jars in a directory, or I can pass a command to the command prompt / shell on an OS to try to find it, is there some better way of doing this?

Comment: Is this your java program? Why not just add a method to spit out the name?

Comment: Because I need to be able to see if it's ALREADY running on a filesystem, so being able to do a thisFile.alreadyRunning() would make more sense than just getting the name of the file.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  It seems if you wrote the code & made the Jars, you should know what you called them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/wherejars.html

```
public class Where
   {
   /**
    * main
    * @param args name of fully qualified class to find, using dots, but no dot class.
    * e.g. java.exe Where javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
     */
   public static void main ( String[] args )
      {
      try
         {
         String qualifiedClassName = args[0];
         Class qc = Class.forName( qualifiedClassName );
         CodeSource source = qc.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
         if ( source != null )
            {
            URL location = source.getLocation();
            System.out.println ( qualifiedClassName + " : " + location );
            }
         else
            {
            System.out.println ( qualifiedClassName + " : " + "unknown source, likely rt.jar" );
            }
         }
      catch ( Exception e )
         {
         System.err.println( "Unable to locate class on command line." );
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }
```